# Formula for calculated value showing as metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, metadata

I have a User who was able to automatically tag files with metadata based on folders in SharePoint per the video https://youtu.be/Tq5zibnXkhY.

However, one attribute is a calculated value, `=TEXT(Today,"YYYY")`, used as the default value.

The formula, `=TEXT(Today,"YYYY")`, is showing as value instead of the calculated value. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: What is the column/data type where you are applying this formula for default value?

Comment: Place where you are trying to set default value is not possible. Calculated formula is not supported by SharePoint while setting default value at Folder level

Answer (score 0):

As per my testing, you cannot use formula in the **Change Default Column Values** settings.

You can only pass the manually entered values in "Default value" section of Change Default Column Values settings.

---

However, if you want this calculation for all folders in the library (Or you can say have the default value at column level irrespective of folder), you can do it via column settings like:

[image]

**Formula used**:

```
=TEXT(Today(),"YYYY")
```

**Output**:

[image]